I deleted "~/.cache/thumbnails" and now 98% of the video thumbnails aren't showing up, how do I fix this?
So yeah, I just installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS a few days ago and I'm trying to get everything up and running.
So I installed Ubuntu 24.04 LTS and I realized none of the video thumbnails were showing up and yeah I know the drill there's something you have to enter in command line to get the thumbnails to show up so I googled and found this File manager in Ubuntu 20.04 not showing thumbnails
Ok so I did this in command line
sudo apt install ffmpegthumbnailer

Ok and that made all the thumbnails appear.
But then out of curiosity just to see what it'd do I went into my Home folder, then went into the .cache folder, and then I sent the "thumbnails" folder to the trash and then emptied the trash and restarted my PC.
When I logged back in lo and behold 98% of the video thumbnails aren't showing up, though pictures are showing up just fine. And the thumbnails folder is there so it came back, just noting that.
Just an FYI, I installed the Nemo file manager and even in Nemo the video thumbnails aren't showing up either.
I was thinking about uninstalling FFMPEG Thumbnailer and then reinstalling it (and if I do need to do this will you please tell me how to uninstall FFMPEG Thumbnailer?) but I'd thought I should seek advice from the Linux experts before I continue.
So what should I do to fix this? I hope I don't have to do a clean install of Ubuntu 24.04 to fix this.

Reproduced steps - same issue. Photos regenerate, yet most videos don't.
Solution: Nemo -> Edit -> Preferences -> Preview -> "Only for files smaller than" set to 1gb
This should solve you issue.
For fun I've tried to uninstall ffmpegthumbnailer. Nemo proceeded to not generate thumbnails (which is weird considering I have other thumbnailers set up in /usr/share/thumbnailers). Reinstalling fixed the issue and kept the preference setting.

Are you on Ubuntu 24.04 LTS?

My bad. I seem to be on 22.04.5 LTS

I tried your solution and it didn't fix it so it looks like I'll have to do a clean install of Ubuntu again. It's frustrating cause I just installed Ubuntu days ago. Though in fact I think I'm gonna take this opportunity to give Mint a shot, I've been wondering about Mint for years and I'm tired of all the bugs I've been experiencing on Ubuntu. Man I've had so many bugs on Ubuntu it's not even funny and I'm just tired of it. I think I'm gonna go see what Mint has to offer.
